# Fail Install node-gyp rebuild on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to run a project in visual code, however whenever I npm install it results in this npm-gyp error, I already installed the latest version of node, npm, python, I also installed python 2.7 and nothing works, I already installed the components essentials, and even the pip.

```
user@ubuntu:~/testeGit/testeGitHub$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> sharp@0.18.4 install /home/user/testeGit/testeGitHub/node_modules/sharp
> node-gyp rebuild

ERROR: https://dl.bintray.com/lovell/sharp/libvips-8.5.5-linux-x64.tar.gz status code 403
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('./binding').download_vips()"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-59-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/testeGit/testeGitHub/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN integradaBibliotecaV2@2.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.18.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.18.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-06-25T01_34_27_616Z-debug.log
```

LOG:
[Log_File_Here](https://pastebin.com/J3yacy2d)

Answer (score 1):

node_modules/sharp is failing to build. You're using an OS that apparently doesn't have pre-built binaries for this node package.

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

Follow the build instructions, and in particular see the libvips section.

You may also want to try updating your package (you are using 0.18.4 whereas the latest is 0.28.3), as

https://dl.bintray.com/lovell/sharp/libvips-8.5.5-linux-x64.tar.gz

is returning a `403 Forbidden` error, meaning either the author has changed the link or that host is no longer hosting it, or perhaps not sharing it to the public.